# Why do we consider the electric field of an infinite plane?

Tags: electrostatics, approximations, models

I never understood why one would calculate the [electric field surrounding an infinite plane](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=%22infinite+plane%22&as_epq=electric+field), if such thing does not exist. Is there physical motivation for using this model? Are the results applicable to real-world systems? Is it because of the mathematical simplicity?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about why a contrived textbook problem exists, rather than physics.

Comment: Infinite planes don't exist, but approximately infinite planes do (as long as the plane is big, and the point of interest is close to it). In this case the (exact) solution for an infinite plane is a good approximation.

Comment: It's exactly for the same reason as why people learn and use Newtonian gravitation before learning and using General Relativity.

Comment: A football field is an infinite plane from the viewpoint of an ant.

Answer (score 5):

In physics and engineering, we often abstract and idealize a physical problem to gain insight into the physics, e.g., infinite plane of charge, infinite line of charge, point charge, etc.

Now, it goes without saying that if these idealizations didn't represent good approximations of relevant physical systems, they wouldn't be used.

With regards to your specific question, imagine a finite conductive plane with uniform electric charge density.  Far enough above (or below) the center of this plane of charge, the infinite plane approximation fails.

*However*, if the distance above the plane is *small* compared to the dimensions of the plane, the electric field is, to a good *approximation*, the electric field of an infinite plane and is *exact* in the limit as the distance above the plane goes to zero.

Another example is the ideal harmonic oscillator.  No physical system is an ideal harmonic oscillator yet, it's easy to show that many systems are, for displacements small enough, *good* approximations of the ideal harmonic oscillator.

Thus the value of studying and solving such ideal systems.